# Error with drawing multiple lines on JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw multiple lines on a `JPanel`. My code adds each line to an `ArrayList` and then a for loop is supposed to iterate through it to draw each line. But I get this odd output instead.

This is my code:

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    /** Generated serial ID for the program. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1697489704611349844L;

    /** The width of the panel. */
    private static final int WIDTH = 600;

    /** The height of the panel. */
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;

    /** The stroke width in pixels. */
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 1;

    /** x-coordinate when mouse is first clicked. */
    private int myX;

    /** y-coordinate when mouse is first clicked. */
    private int myY;

    /** x-coordinate when mouse is clicked for a second time. */
    private int myXEnd;

    /** y-coordinate when mouse clicked for a second time. */
    private int myYEnd;

    /** ArrayList of lines drawn. */
    private List<Line2D> myLines = new ArrayList<Line2D>();

    /** ArrayList of coordinates to draw with a pencil. */
    private List<MouseEvent> myPoints = new ArrayList<MouseEvent>();


    /**
     * Constructs a new ellipse panel.
     */
    public DrawPanel() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        addMouseListener(myMouseHandler);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouseMotionHandler);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
    }

    /**
     * MouseMotionListener for drawing a shape.
     */
    private final MouseMotionListener myMouseMotionHandler = new MouseMotionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent theEvent) {
            myXEnd = theEvent.getX();
            myYEnd = theEvent.getY();
            myPoints.add(theEvent);
            repaint(); 
        }

//        @Override
//        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {          
//        }

    };

    /**
     * MouseListener for drawing a shape.
     */
    private final MouseListener myMouseHandler = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent theEvent) {
            myX = theEvent.getX();
            myY = theEvent.getY();
            myXEnd = theEvent.getX();
            myYEnd = theEvent.getY();
            repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent theEvent) {
            myXEnd = theEvent.getX();
            myYEnd = theEvent.getY();

            myPoints.add(theEvent);
            repaint();            
        }
    };

    /**
     * Draws line with drawLine method.
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics theGraphics) {
        super.paintComponent(theGraphics);
        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) theGraphics;

        // for better graphics display
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                             RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setPaint(new Color(51, 0, 111));
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH));

        myLines.add(new Line2D.Double(myX, myY, myXEnd, myYEnd));

        for (Line2D l : myLines) {
            g2d.draw(l);
        }  
    }
}
```

And here's what it draws on the panel when I move the cursor in a circle. It's a bunch of lines connected at a center point. But I want it to be able to draw multiple separate lines.
[[image: 1]]

And this is the type of line I'd like to draw, but multiple of them without previous drawn lines disappearing. Hence, why I implemented an ArrayList to redraw lines to keep them on the panel.

[[image: 2]]

Comment: What do you expect to happen? It sounds like you want free form pencil drawing.

Comment: I'd like for it to be separate lines. I can draw one line but it disappears once I draw another one. I'd like for all of the lines to be present on the panel.

Comment: The 'free form' pencil drawing is separate lines, they are just very short.

Comment: I see that. I updated my post to show what I'd like my lines to be like.

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood. Are you calling mylines.clear() anywhere? Your array list should keep growing and in the repaint it should draw more and more lines. Also you shouldn't add the lines in your paint method.

Comment: No, I'm not calling myLines.clear() anywhere. Maybe adding my lines in my paint method is what's causing my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason the lines are disappearing is not shown in this code. Here is how I would update it.

```
   @Override
    public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent theEvent) {
        myXEnd = theEvent.getX();
        myYEnd = theEvent.getY();
        repaint(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent theEvent) {
        myX = theEvent.getX();
        myY = theEvent.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent theEvent) {
        myXEnd = theEvent.getX();
        myYEnd = theEvent.getY();
        myLines.add(new Line2D.Double(myX, myY, myXEnd, myYEnd));
        repaint();            
    }
};

/**
 * Draws line with drawLine method.
 */
@Override
public void paintComponent(final Graphics theGraphics) {
    super.paintComponent(theGraphics);
    final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) theGraphics;

    // for better graphics display
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2d.setPaint(new Color(51, 0, 111));
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH));

    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(myX, myY, myXEnd, myYEnd));

    for (Line2D l : myLines) {
        g2d.draw(l);
    }  
}
```

This will draw one line between the two points, and it will not store the line until the mouse is released. If you actually want it to draw like a pencil, add the new line in the mouse dragged method too.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions and it (almost) worked. There was a minor error, it drew new lines but it all had a start point at the upper-left corner. But I fixed it and now it works, so thank you!

Comment: But your users will want to see the new line as it is being drawn. Try drawing a horizontal line when you can't see it until the buttonUp event.